# AWS Event Bridge NotAuthorizedForSourceException

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge

I just set up AWS Guard Duty to notify alerts via slack and am trying to test the setup. I try to send this event on my event bus

```
  "version": "0",
  "detail-type": "GuardDuty Finding",
  "source": "aws.guardduty",
  "account": "187760472520",
  "time": "2024-02-28T16:46:43Z",
  "region": "us-west-2",
  "resources": [],
  "detail": {
    "severity": 3.5,
    "description": "Example GuardDuty finding"
  }
}
```

And the error message is:  `Error. NotAuthorizedForSourceException. Not authorized for the source.`

Per [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/APIReference/API_PutEventsResultEntry.html) the error is: `You do not have permissions to publish events with this source onto this event bus.`

I am using the template resource base policy on my event bus.

```
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [{
    "Sid": "AllowAccountToPutEvents",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
      "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<Account ID>:root"
    },
    "Action": "events:PutEvents",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:events:us-west-2:<Account ID>:event-bus/default"
  }, {
    "Sid": "AllowAllAccountsFromOrganizationToPutEvents",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": "*",
    "Action": "events:PutEvents",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:events:us-west-2:<Account ID>:event-bus/default",
    "Condition": {
      "StringEquals": {
        "aws:PrincipalOrgID": "<Org ID>"
      }
    }
  }, {
    "Sid": "AllowAccountToManageRulesTheyCreated",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
      "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<Account ID>:root"
    },
    "Action": ["events:PutRule", "events:PutTargets", "events:DeleteRule", "events:RemoveTargets", "events:DisableRule", "events:EnableRule", "events:TagResource", "events:UntagResource", "events:DescribeRule", "events:ListTargetsByRule", "events:ListTagsForResource"],
    "Resource": "arn:aws:events:us-west-2:<Account ID>:rule/default",
    "Condition": {
      "StringEqualsIfExists": {
        "events:creatorAccount": "<Account ID>"
      }
    }
  }]
}
```

I know that my user in the console has permissions to do this.

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like I cannot manually create and send an eventbus event with `"source": "aws.guardduty"`, but a work around to testing guard duty events is to [generate sample findings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/guardduty/latest/ug/sample_findings.html). This will trigger your cloudwatch rule many times if it is configured correctly, thus sending events on the eventbus to trigger SNS.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).